# How to find the date of highest stock price with python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a python data frame like this
[column: stock_id, row price with date index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNnmA.png)

I want to know the highest price and the date of every stock_id.

I don't know how to do it.

When I use "price.iloc[-200:].max()" to show the highest stock price in the latest 200 date for every stock, it only show the price for every stock but no date.

[the highest price of every stock but no date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oss9Z.png)

If I only try this for one stock with "price['0050'].max()", how can I get the highest price and the date?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you share an example of your dataframe instead of picture? Thanks!

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to show your code instead of post it in image

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find out the max value for a given stock, use loc.

```
stock_data = df.loc[df['stock name'][-200:].idxmax()]
```

Which gives you the row that contains the max value for the last 200 days of all stocks for that given stock, which means you need to get rid of the rest of them.

```
index = stock_data.name
value = stock_data['stock name']
```

It is not a pretty solution, but it works.

One that does the same for for all is:

```
# create a temporary data frame with the last 200 days
df_200 = df[-200:]

res = []
# go through each stock
for stock in list(df):
    df_t = df_200.loc[df_200[stock].idxmax()]
    value = df_t[stock]
    index = df_t.name
    res.append([index, stock, value])
```

Then you can store/use the results however you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_ms['High'].idxmax()
```

Here 'df_ms' refers my dataframe, 'High' refers my column/variable in dataframe and idxmax() returns the max valued index for given attribute

(which returns date in which stock value is maximum)